# Delete all rows in sheet 1 with same value in column as in sheet 2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to achieve the example i provided below, deleting all rows in sheet1 that are similar to sheet2.

**Sheet1**

```
   Name             ID
-------------------------
 1. Name11         Value1
 2. Name22         Value2
 3. Name33         Value3
 4. Name44         Value4
 5. Name55         Value5
    ...            ...
```

**Sheet2**

```
   Name             ID
-------------------------
 1. Name13         Value3
 2. Name52         Value5
    ...            ...
```

**Sheet1 After deleting the row**

```
   Name             ID
-------------------------
 1. Name11         Value1
 2. Name22         Value2
 3. Name44         Value4
    ...
```

Comment: What is your doubt? This can be achieved easily by reading both sheets with SpreadsheetApp (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) editing the data for sheet1 and saving it back to the sheet after you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rg1=sh1.getDataRange();
  var rg2=sh2.getDataRange();
  var v1A=rg1.getValues();
  var v2A=rg2.getValues();
  for(var i=v1A.length-1;i>0;i--)
  {
    var row1=v1A[i];
    for(var j=1;j<v2A.length;j++)
    {
      row2=v2A[j];
      if(row1.join()==row2.join())
      {
        sh1.deleteRow(i+1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i updated the table and only the data in the column ID(B) are the same, i tried the code but it was not successfully.